# What is the most efficient way of freeing the memory allocated to a massive vector?

Tags: c++

I have a massive  `std::vector<strc> V` filled with more than 100M elements, which I use as the input of some function `foo`. Here, `strc` 
 is simply a `struct` containing three primitives. After the call to `foo` finishes, I don't have any purpose for `V`, so I want to reclaim as much memory from it as possible. Clearly `V.clear()` doesn't do the job as `V` retains its capacity.

I have read some suggestion advocating for the trick `std::vector<strc>().swap(V)`, but it looks rather gimmicky an not good practice. I'm not even sure if it does what I need!. Is there a standard way of doing this? If indeed `swap` is the best option, should I call `clear` first? Since the complexity of `swap` is constant, it seems that `swap` is literally exchanging the address of `V` with that of an empty, nameless vector. Then, what happens with all the stuff that was originally in `V`? I expect it to remain in memory but no longer accessible. Does that chunk of memory gets directly marked as free after the swap? i.e., gets somehow deallocated?

Other sources suggest `V.clear()` and then `V.shrink_to_fit()`. Is this a better option?

Comment: Your best bet to pick the best strategy is to look at the documentation for each one of these methods, and understand exactly what they do. It is no mystery what `clear()` does, or what `shrink_to_fit()` does, for example. Have you read their actual documentation yet? It's in every good C++ book, or even on cppreference.com.  If you haven't, why not? Knowing where to find and how to read technical documentation is something that every C++ developer should know, and be able to do.

Comment: Too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Technically*, the only guaranteed way to ensure that there is no allocation remaining is to destroy the vector (and not replace with a new one).

In practice though, both the swapping with default constructed, and clear + shrink will work.

---

> ```
> std::vector<strc>().swap(V)
> ```
>
> Then, what happens with all the stuff that was originally in V?

It is swapped into the temporary, which is destroyed at the end of the full expression, thereby destroying the elements and freeing the allocation.

The rather theoretical issue is that default constructing a vector - which will be swapped into `V` - is technically not guaranteed to not allocate a massive array. In practice it won't, so this is fine.

> If indeed swap is the best option, should I call clear first?

This is not necessary. Destruction of the elements is handled by the destructor of the vector.

> Other sources suggest V.clear() and then V.shrink_to_fit(). Is this a better option?

It is certainly clearer in the intention.

But, `shrink_to_fit` is technically not guaranteed to actually shrink the capacity - it is a request that the implementation isn't obliged to follow - so this isn't any more guaranteed to free memory than the swap solution. In practice, I don't see a reason for any implementation to not free any allocation of an empty vector, so this should also be fine in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a scope:

```
{
    std::vector<strc> V;
    // ...
    foo(V);
}
// ...
```

Comment: The vector is an element of another object and I need some other stuff in that object to live after foo. Any other option?